# Filter rows that have ALMOST matching columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have rows with several columns. I would like to **take out** the rows where the text in column B **isn't contained** in column C.

This is an example sheet. I would want to trim this data down **so only rows 2 and 4 remain**. A caveat is that there's an extra space between the street numbers and the street names in the ADDRESS 2 columns, so an exact match won't work.

[image: Example Sheet]

To me it doesn't matter if it is a filter, or filling cells in another sheet with formulas, but I do not know macros (yet). Either way, any help is appreciated! This is a set of over 300k rows and about 70 columns.

Comment: See [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

Comment: You could use `Replace` to get rid of all of the white space and then compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-vba approach is given below:

Formula is `=IF(B2=SUBSTITUTE(C2,"  "," "),"","Remove")`

[image]

Then Sort on Check, Filter Check on `Not = Remove` and copy filtered cells to a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is transform columns B and C so that there are no spaces within each string, like so

```
For i = 2 to Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Cells(i,2) = Replace(Cells(i,2), " ", "")
    Cells(i,3) = Replace(Cells(i,3), " ", "")
Next i
```

and then you can compare the two for a direct match. I trust you can take it from there, but if not, one approach would be to loop again and delete any instance where the two columns did not equal

```
For i = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.RowsCount) to 2 Step -1
    if Cells(i,2) <> Cells(i,3) then
        Cells(i,1).EntireRow.Delete
    end if 
Next i
```

Of course, this assumes you only need to look at the row visited in the loop for your matches (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a conditional formatting and color and afterwards filter on color and remove the selected.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub KeepMatchingData()
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lc = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
Range(Cells(2, lc), Cells(lr, lc)).Formula = "=IF(TRIM(B2)=TRIM(C2),ROW(),NA())"
On Error Resume Next
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=lc, Header:=xlYes
Range(Cells(2, lc), Cells(lr, lc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
Range(Cells(2, lc), Cells(lr, lc)).Clear
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```